# Counting specific sets of repeats

Tags: r

I am having to write code in r where I have to count the number of times a specific set of numbers within a vector are repeated one after another.

For example, in the following set of numbers, I would want to count the number of times a number was repeated after itself, such as 2,2 and 4,4, or even repeating after itself 3 times in a row such as 1,1,1 or 3,3,3, not counting the number of times an individual number has occurred throughout the set.

```
5, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 6, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 6, 5, 6, 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rle` to find repeated consecutive values. For example,

```
i1 <- rle(x)
setNames(i1$lengths[i1$lengths > 1], paste0('value:', i1$values[i1$lengths > 1]))
#value:2 value:4 value:5 value:4 value:6 value:1 value:2 value:3 value:2 
#      2       2       2       2       2       3       2       3       2
```

**DATA**

```
dput(x)
c(5, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 6, 4, 5, 5, 
3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
3, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 6, 5, 6, 3)
```

Comment: Or using `rle` and `table`: `f <- function(x) {r <- rle(x); idx <- r$lengths > 1;  table('value' = r$values[idx], 'length' = r$lengths[idx]) }; f(x)`